# applying a function to a pair of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have two series:

```
s = pd.Series([20, 21, 12]
t = pd.Series([17,19 , 11]
```

I want to apply a two argument function to the two series to get a series of results (as a series). Now, one way to do it is as follows:

```
df = pd.concat([s, t], axis=1)
result = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x[s], x[t]), axis=1)
```

But this seems clunky. Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: Are you sure that `lambda x: foo(x[s], x[t])` is correct?  Don't you mean to simply apply `foo` row-wise to each pair of `s` and `t` values? What does `foo` look like?

Comment: @Rodalm What does it matter? It is a function which takes two args. And yes, I do just want to apply foo row-wise.

Comment: Because it doesn't work as it is, and makes your solution unnecessarily complicated. You just need `result = df.apply(foo, axis=1) `,  making your solution more elegant. Or if you want `result = pd.concat([s, t], axis=1).apply(foo, axis=1)`

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do what you want.

Depending on the function in question, you may be able to apply it directly to the series. For example, calling `s + t` returns

```
0    37
1    40
2    23
dtype: int64
```

However, if your function is more complicated than simple arithmetic, you may need to get creative. One option is to use the built-in Python `map` function. For example, calling

`list(map(np.add, s, t))`

returns

`[37, 40, 23]`

Answer (score 1):

If the two series have the same index, you can create a series with list comprehension:

```
result = pd.Series([foo(xs, xt) for xs,xt in zip(s,t)], index=s.index)
```

If you can't guarantee that the two series have the same index, concat is the way to go as it helps align the index.

Comment: That is certainly a nice solution,  which had not occurred to me because it seems like going through a list incurs a lot of overhead. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong :-). `apply` would create an equivalent of a list as well, plus some overhead for index alignment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you can use this to apply a function using 2 colums and copy the results in another column:

```
df['result'] = df.loc[:, ['s', 't']].apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to use `numpy.vectorize`:

```py
from numpy import vectorize

vect_foo = vectorize(foo)
result = vect_foo(s, t)
```